# Blade css view not reflecting changes

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am editing an CSS files , but non of any changes is reflected or updated in laravel view .
I tried the following:-

```
php artisan view:clear
artisan clear-compiled
php artisan cache:clear
```

I also  deleted the cache file manually in storage\framework\views.
Refreshed the browser many times => ctrl + F5

Comment: Are you actually editing the CSS in the public/ folder or are you editing CSS/Sass in the resources/ folder?

Comment: I am editing css located in /public/css

Comment: Are you linking the stylesheet in the HTML? A fresh Laravel installation doesn't link the stylesheet by default.

Comment: Yes . I am linking through html , the style is already implemented but changing in same css file. Does not effect any thing

Comment: Sometimes the browser caches the CSS file check this by removing cookies and refreshing the page. If you start using Laravel mix it has a function called version(). This will stop the browser from caching.

Comment: I deleted the browser cache , cookies , tried in different browser in same PC  and tried on my mobile browser. All is given the same results . In web browser > view page soruce > custom-min.css (file) . I see the background color code is still old one , I opened the custom.min.css in notepad and i see that it have the changes that i made in IDE

Comment: i got the same problem... any answers???

Comment: If you're using Cloudlfare for SSL, then there's a setting for development mode. Switch that on and your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing same issue but i tried with adding time() to its version and it worked!
for Example:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('css/style.css?v=').time()}}">
```